# Правильно или не правильно работает транзистор

Tags: электроника

[image: Схема]

Почему напряжение теряется на транзисторе, а не идет дальше. U(верх)20V, U(справа)300V.  [Datasheet транзистора](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/108019/STMICROELECTRONICS/STGF10NB60SD.html)

Comment: -2 без комментариев?

Comment: -3 С комментарием, вы ошиблись ресурсом с данным вопросом.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не формат для SO.

Comment: Расширю ответ @Other — это сайт по программированию, а не электронике.

Answer (score 6):

Всё правильно работает.
В данной схеме транзистор подключен по так называемой схеме **с общим эмиттером**.
Потенциал на эмиттере не может превышать потенциал на затворе - иначе транзистор закроется.
Эта схема полезна для стабилизации напряжения - напряжение на нагрузке повторяет напряжение не затворе(*за вычетом падения напряжения на переходах, не уверен, каких именно в БТИЗ*). Уменьшайте сопротивление нагрузки, ток будет расти, а напряжение будет оставаться стабильным.

Если вы хотите коммутировать 300В на нагрузке - перенесите сопротивление нагрузки из цепи эмиттера в цепь коллектора.

---

Рассмотрим обе схемы:

[image: Схема]

Будем менять напряжение V5 от 0 до 15V с шагом 0.2:

[image: график]

Видим, что на напряжение на R1 почти в точности повторяет напряжение на затворе(с постоянной разностью), а напряжение на R2 скачкообразно меняется с открытием транзистора.
Также стоит отметить инверсию сигнала на R2 - закрытый канал выдаёт максимальное напряжение, открытый - минимальное.